# 'Under' preposition meaning?

Tags: prepositions, expressions

> The war between Iran and Iraq lasted ***under*** a decade and caused a great deal of bloodshed.

Is this ***under*** usage equal to *by, some, nearly ... etc, or throughout, through ... etc*, or else none of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking the specific meaning of "under" in the first sentence.  In context, it means "less than".  As used it is not very specific, so it could be 1 day less than a decade or 3 years less.